# Whats app bulk messages sender

Tags: c#, winforms, whatsapp

I want to make windows based Whats App bulk messages sender application.
I tried WhatsApi (http://github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAPINet/) to do that, but I found too many limitations and problems. 
I want to ask that, I there another way to send bulk whats app messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending bulk messages are against WhatsApps Terms of Service Agreement. WhatsApp offers users functionality to send broadcast messages, but with a maximum of recipients AND recipients will only receive your message if they have already saved your number in their contact list.

WhatsApp's Terms of Service Agreement states that you may not use the service to send bulk messages (in other words more messages than a normal person would be able to send during a specific time). This keeps their servers from being overwhelmed and keeps advertisers from abusing WhatsApp messages. You can, however, try to write a function to select x number of contacts and send the message, then repeat the function until all intended recipients have been messaged.